# acceder a this en callback ecma6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript

Amigos, tengo el siguiente codigo :

Objeto Seleccion (en el metodo obtener está el codigo relevante):

```
class Seleccion extends React.Component{

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
        image : null,
        selecciones:[]
    }
    this.obtener();
}

obtener(){
    var seleccion = this;
    API.consulta({
        metodo: 'listas/selecciones',
        'callback': function (r) {
            console.log("can we proccess?",r);
            let selecciones = [];
            selecciones.push = r.selecciones;
            seleccion.setState({
                selecciones:r.selecciones
            })
            console.log("cambiado 2",seleccion.state);


        }
    });
}
//más codigo de la clase seleccion
```

}

API.js

```
 consulta: function (data) {
        console.log("llamada desde API");
        let parametros = this.default;
        console.log("binding this?",data);
        let url = this.obtUrl(data.metodo);

        if (!data.hasOwnProperty('metodo'))  throw Error('No se ha pasado el metodo a consultar');
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty('callback'))  throw Error('No se ha pasado la funcion callback');

        parametros = Object.assign({},this.default,{
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: url
        })

        console.log("url",parametros.url);
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('parametros')) parametros = $.extend(this.default, data.parametros);

        if (data.hasOwnProperty('data'))
            parametros.data = data.data;

        $.ajax(parametros)
            .done(data.callback)
            .fail(function(){
                console.log("something wrong");
            })
        ;
    },
```

En estos momentos, necesito acceder en la función callback al objeto "seleccion" para realizar cambios al estado, según la respuesta. Pero si paso un ".bind(this)" al metodo consulta me explota. como puedo hacer?.

El tema es que con la consulta ajax obtengo la data de "selecciones" y según el resultado, deberé modificar el estado de la misma para renderizarlos, es por ello que necesito desde la función *callback* acceder al objeto **Seleccion**.
**PD** : sé, que sobreescribiendo la variable o renombrandola podría acceder, pero entiendo que con ecma6 hay una forma nueva. ¿es así? gracias.

Comment: Aclara algunas cosas. A que te refieres con el objeto "seleccion"?, al objeto `API` o el objeto que le pasas como parametro a la funcion consulta?. Con respecto a lo de ecmascript6, no se de que utilidad seria para ti si lo que estas escribiendo es codigo del lado del cliente, a menos que tengas algun compilador de ES6 a ES5

Comment: Creo que el problema fue que no copie el codigo completo, modificaré el post para que lo visualices bien. Con respecto a lo de es6 y es5. Si, efectivamente estoy trabajando con es6 y compilando por medio de babel.

Comment: Ok, fijate en la actualizacion que le di a mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es cambiar el contexto de `this` en tu callback con ES5, bastaria con crear una copia de este con ayuda de `bind` de la siguiente manera (por ejemplo):

```
.done(data.callback.bind(data))
```

Pasando como parametro a `bind` el valor de `this` que quieres usar.

En caso de ES6 podrias solucionarlo con la implementacion de arrow functions `() => { }`. Fijate en `methodA` de la clase `A` del siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var API = {
  query: data => {
    // Algo asincrono como un ajax iria aqui...
    // Simulemos con setTimeout:
    setTimeout(data.callback, 1000);
  }
};

class A {
  constructor() { this.state = false }
  
  methodA() {
    API.query({
      callback: () => {
        this.state = true;
        console.log(Object.keys(this));
      }
    });
  }
  
  methodB() {
    API.query({
      callback: function() {
        console.log(Object.keys(this));
      }
    });
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.methodA(); // Propiedades de la clase A (objeto 'a')
a.methodB(); // Objeto window
```

Comment: Allí actualicé el código, gracias por responder. En estos momentos, así me funciona, sin embargo, la consola me está dando un warning de que accedo incorrectamente al objeto. Si te fijas, lo que hice fue renombrar la variable y accederle con el nuevo nombre en la función callback. la idea era entender como se puede hacer esto correctamente segun ecmascript6

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Perfecto